# Regression covariance

Tags: descriptive-statistics

2. Suppose that we are interested in
   the relationship between the age
   of the individuals who are members
   of our managed-care organization
   and the use of physician
   care, as measured by visits. Suppose
   also that after selecting 15
   members at random we obtained
   the following paired observations:
   Visits: 3 5 4 2 1 3 6 7 4 5 10 1 2 3 8
   Age 28 45 50 19 16 27 54 63 32
   42 68 19 23 30 61
   Use these data to find the covariance
   between age and the number
   of visits.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a [covariance](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Covariance.html) formula

$$\text{Cov}(x,y) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i = 1}^N(x_i-\bar x)(y_i-\bar y)$$
where $x,y$ are lists of data and $\bar x, \bar y$ are the means.